# How to check if an SWF file loaded (ActionScript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

How do I check if an [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) file loaded?

I want to execute a script when an SWF file has finished loading,

```
root.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
root.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace("onProgress");
}

function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
    trace("onComplete");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `root.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete)` instead.

Comment: root.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete) is working

root.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
onProgress not working

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by sending the `dispatchEvent` from the loading SWF file to the loaded SWF file:

- In the loading SWF file: when the load is complete, do `dispatchEvent(new Event("Bla-bla"));`
- In the loaded SWF file: `addEventListener("Bla-bla", someHandler);`

First SWF file:

`var load:Loader = new Loader(new URLReauest("name of loaded swf"));`
`load.addEventListener(Event.Complete, completeHandler);`

`function completeHandler(event:Event):void`
`{`
`var currentLoadedSWF:MovieClip = event.target.loader;`
`currentLoader.dispatchEvent(new Event("Bla-Bla"))`
    `}`

In the second SWF file, in the constructor, put in this code:

```
addEventListener("Bla-Bla", someHandler)
```

Or you can call any public methods in the loaded SWF file.